# TypeError: 'question_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function in django 2.0 tutorial

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am fairly new to django and I am trying to follow the tutorial ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/ ) but have encountered the above error.

Here is my code for the `models.py`

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200),
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Also the question text and choice text is not appearing on the django-admin page

[image: Django Admin screenshot]

Comment: where appear that error? Did you run makemigrations and migrated?

Comment: Yes, I have done the makemigrations and migrated as well. They appear when I create a question manually on the shell.

Comment: Do you have some other `Question` object in the database? Please go to the shell and type `from <your_app>.models import Question` then `Question._meta.get_fields()` and put what return

Comment: Here's what I am getting: (<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: pub_date>)

Answer (score 0):

In django, `modelname_somefieldname` is a system operator syntax, so the reason of your error is the `question_text` keyword contains `question_`. The `question` is a model name.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when you don't have that field in your table. As you show me there are only two fields registered (`Id`, `pub_date`). Please make migrations and migrate again if that didn't work, delete everything in the folder `migrations` and make migrations again

Comment: It seems that the models are not being migrated properly. I have tried to delete the migrations folder of the polls app and did the migrate, makemigrations but the issue is still the same.

Comment: @AbrielJohnGabriel check if the file in migrations folder exist and have all the fields

Comment: Yes they're there.